# How to automatically get user data when accessing the website in nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

Can nextjs 13 automatically get user data when accessing the website with accessToken in localStorage?

I use nextjs 13 to create a website but i don't know what component i can put get user data code inside.

I am a beginner. Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using context to save userdata rather than localStorage in nextjs, if you use localStorage you encounter HYDRATION errors;
initially you should get userdata from cookies in serverSideProps, to achieve it use following instructions:

```js
// you should save userData in cookies when fetching, in nextjs i recommend you using library to save or get value
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next';

const BROWSER_TOKEN_KEY = 'TOKEN';
const BROWSER_USER_DATA_KEY = 'USER_DATA';

const response = fetch('/getUserDataFromApiUrl')
setCookie(BROWSER_USER_DATA_KEY, response.data);

// ************************************************************************
// it is common function, so you should call this function in every file in your pages folder, except _app and _document files

const sharedServerSideLogic = (getServerSidePropsFunc) => {
  return async function (context) {
    const token = context.req.cookies[BROWSER_TOKEN_KEY];
    const userData = context.req.cookies[BROWSER_USER_DATA_KEY];

    const { props: ssr_props, ...rest } = getServerSidePropsFunc ? await getServerSidePropsFunc(context) : { props: {} };

    return {
        props: {
          cookieInitialValues: {
            userData: isAuth ? userData : null, // if user not logged in then userdata should be null
            isAuth: token // it is not the best solution to save if user is logged in or not, but it works
          },
          ...ssr_props,
        },
        ...rest,
    };
  };
};

// ************************************************************************
// and when you want to write your own logic in getServerSideProps function you can use it like this:
// for example index.js file:

const Homepage = () => {
  return <>Your JSX</>
}

export const getServerSideProps= sharedServerSideLogic((context) => {
  // write here your logic

  return {
    props: {
      // values
    }
  }
});

// ******************************************************************
// CREATE CONTEXT

import { useContext, createContext } from 'react';

const CookieContext =  createContext();

const CoookieProvider = ({ children, initialValues }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues)

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues(initialValues);
  }, [initialValues])

  return (
    <CookieContext.Provider value={values}>
      {children}
    </CookieContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useCookieValues() {
  return useContext(CookieContext)
};

export {
  CoookieProvider,
  useCookieValues
};

// ******************************************************************
// Use context in your app.js:

const App = (props) => {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <CoookieProvider initalValues={pageProps.cookieInitialValues}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </CoookieProvider>
  )
}

// When you want to use values saved in cookies you can get it by using this hook
// How you use values in cookies is up to you.
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const cookieValues = useCookieValues();
  const userData = cookieValues.userData;

  return <></>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to get user data from the server with the access token and this request can be sent in app/page.ts or app/layout.ts.

Comment: I can send a request from app/layout.ts but i must add "use client" to layout.ts. I don't like this solution

Comment: If you just use "fetch" request, you don't need to add "use client".

Comment: I use react-query to send request without useEffect + axios

Comment: I didn't use react-query, if this library needs to add "use client", you can try to create a new file to send request, and call a function in this file from your layout.ts file. Maybe you can give me a sample code for your situation by any share code platform.